# Synchronization mechanisms in apscheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

I would like to ask about synchronization mechanisms implemented in APScheduler. There is no mention in the documentation. The following code seems to work properly, but I would like to be sure that concurrent access to shared variable cannot lead to race condition.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

class Test(object):
    x = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def step_up(self):
        self.x += 1
        ts = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        print(f'Step up {ts}: value of x={self.x}')

    def step_heavy(self):
        self.x += -1
        ts = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        print(f'Heavy 1 {ts}: value of x={self.x}')
        np.random.random(size=(20000, 20000))
        self.x += -1
        ts = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        print(f'Heavy 2 {ts}: value of x={self.x}')
        np.random.random(size=(20000, 50000))
        self.x += -1
        ts = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        print(f'Heavy 3 {ts}: value of x={self.x}')

    def update_setpoint(self):
        pass


test = Test()
scheduler.add_job(test.step_up, 'interval', seconds=1)
scheduler.add_job(test.step_heavy, 'interval', seconds=15)
scheduler.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)

except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    scheduler.shutdown()
```

Comment: use a proper synchronization primitive instead of a instance variable because what you have shown can most certainly lead to a race condition

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now can lead to race conditions. Since under the hood `BackgroundScheduler` uses threads, you will need a primitive that restricts access to the attribute to one thread at a time.

```
from ctypes import c_int
from multiprocessing import Value

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = Value(c_int, 0)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x.value
    
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x.value = value
    
    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
    # rest of the code remains the same
    ...
```

This will now prevent race conditions between the different threads as the attribute will be locked when a thread attempts to update the value.